# Search Directory for Files Matching Pattern - Windows

Tags: windows, cmd

I have been trying to make this work for longer than I care to admit but for some reason I cannot figure it out. I usually work with Linux/Unix.

I simply want to search a directory for all instances where a filename matches a string.

Some things I have tried:

`dir /s "/path/to/Test*"`

`dir /s/b "C:/path/to/Test*"`

Additionally, I am hoping to return something that can easily be imported into an array. Something without unnecessary information. All I need Is the path or at the very least the filename for each file matched.

Edit: I dont want information like this (if possible)

```
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is...
```

Edit: `Test*` is intended to indicate all filenames beginning with `Test`. So `TestA`, `TestB`, & `TestC` should all match.

Comment: Using forward slashes for file paths is unreliable with CMD's internal commands, and also many external commands. I don't have a detailed list of which commands work with forward slashes in certain (not all) cases and which always require backslash. I've just been randomly tripped up many times when I accidentally used the wrong separator. Always use backslash as the path separator in CMD. OTOH, PowerShell commands should always support using forward slash as the path separator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same commands work on Linux, Mac, and Windows. http://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/

```
PS C:\src> (Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Path 'C:/src/d2' -Filter 'test*').FullName
C:\src\d2\test.bat
C:\src\d2\test.ps1
C:\src\d2\test.sql
C:\src\d2\test.txt
C:\src\d2\copyt\test.txt
```

Using command aliases, it can be shorter for interactive use. But, aliases are not a good practice for scripts.

```
PS C:\src> (ls -r -file 'C:/src/d2/test*').FullName
C:\src\d2\test.bat
C:\src\d2\test.ps1
C:\src\d2\test.sql
C:\src\d2\test.txt
C:\src\d2\copyt\test.txt
```

If you want an array, this will make one.

```
PS C:\src> $files = (ls -r -file 'C:/src/d2/test*').FullName
PS C:\src> $files.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

Replace directory separators with -replace.

```
(Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path 'C:/src/d2' -Filter 'test.*').FullName -replace '\\','/'
```

Join them to a single line with -join. This join uses a COMMA. Note that if the join uses a COLON in *NIX-style, it will not work well on Windows.

```
PS C:\src> (Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path 'C:/src/d2' -Filter 'test.*').FullName -replace '\\','/' -join (',')
C:/src/d2/test.bat,C:/src/d2/test.ps1,C:/src/d2/test.sql,C:/src/d2/test.txt,C:/src/d2/copyt/test.txt
```

If you need a PATH-style separator, use:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path 'C:/src/d2' -Filter 'test.*').FullName -replace '\\','/' -join ([IO.Path]::PathSeparator)
```

Comment: After trying this, it seems to work as I need. Two additional questions about this solution. First is there any way to (without too much additional overhead) return the filenames with forward slashes instead? Second, id like to add a delimiter to the response. How might one accomplish this? The first question is much less important than the second

Comment: @Newb4YouBB, are you looking for a CSV or PATH style list on one line?

Comment: So let me explain my situation some. I need an array of file names matching a pattern for use in PHP. Traditionally (with Linux) I would do this with `find` however because I am testing this locally, I need a (near) equivalent solution for windows. Because this is just for testing it doesn't need to be a perfect solution. I'm just hoping to get the array or something easily changed to an array so that the rest of the script can remain the same.

Comment: Thank you for your additional help. The replace operator doesn't seem to want to work for me but I can take it from here.

Answer (score 1):

I've just been searching for all files, called "test.*" all over my C:-drive, using this simple command:

```
dir /S C:\test*
```

Although I just mention the directory `C:\`, the `/S` makes sure all subfolders are used too. In top of that, there are no double quotes, as you can see.

Does this solve your issue?

Comment: So when I perform this without quotes it tells me one of my directory names is not in the correct format. When I do add the quotes it informs me that the file is not found when I indeed know the file exists and is in the proper location.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I didn't see that you're used working with UNIX/Linux, so here I have an approach you'll prefer:

```
forfiles /P C:\ /S /M test* /C "cmd /c echo @path"
```

This does the following:

```
/P C:\              Start looking in C:\
/S                  Search through subdirectories
/M test*            Filename looks like "test*"
/C <cmd>            When found, launch <cmd>
"cmd /c echo @path" Echo (write to output) the complete path of the found file or directory
```

This will give you a list of files and directories, written as full paths, something like:

```
"C:\Octave\Octave-5.2.0\mingw64\bin\test-libiberty.exe"
"C:\Octave\Octave-5.2.0\mingw64\bin\test-lua.exe"
"C:\Octave\Octave-5.2.0\mingw64\bin\test-tinyxml.exe"
"C:\Octave\Octave-5.2.0\mingw64\include\llvm\Testing"         <-- this is a directory
"C:\Octave\Octave-5.2.0\mingw64\include\wx-3.0\wx\testing.h"
...
```

Which resembles a lot the typical UNIX/Linux results, you're used to.

More information about `forfiles` can be found, launching `forfiles /?`.

Answer (score 0):

Based upon your statement, "I am hoping to return something that can easily be imported into an array", I'd assume you're probably looking for something more like this:

```batch-file
@Echo Off
Rem Ensure that extensions are enabled (required for SET and FOR commands)
SetLocal EnableExtensions
Rem Ensures that there are no existing variables in the environment with names beginning with file[
For /F "Delims==" %%G In ('" Set file[ 2> NUL "') Do Set "%%G="
Rem Gets every file matching the glob test* in the tree rooted at "C:\path\to"
Rem and defines an incremented variable name for each, beginning at %file[1]%
For /F "Tokens=1,* Delims=]" %%G In (
    '" Dir /B /S /A-D "C:\path\to\test*" 2> NUL | "%__AppDir__%find.exe" /N /V "" "'
) Do Set "file%%G]=%%H"
Rem An example line to show you all of the variables you have now defined
Set file[ 2> NUL
Rem Pause the script to ensure that you have been able to read any output
Pause
Rem An example line to show you all the first defined variable value
Echo=%file[1]%
Rem Pause the script to ensure that you have been able to read any output
Pause
```

...and here it is without the `Rem`arks:

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
For /F "Delims==" %%G In ('" Set file[ 2> NUL "') Do Set "%%G="
For /F "Tokens=1,* Delims=]" %%G In (
    '" Dir /B /S /A-D "C:\path\to\test*" 2> NUL | "%__AppDir__%find.exe" /N /V "" "'
) Do Set "file%%G]=%%H"
Set file[ 2> NUL
Pause
Echo=%file[1]%
Pause
```

*Don't forget to change `C:\path\to\test*` as required for your specific location and glob.*

Comment: I havent yet attempted this solution. I am planning to use this with PHP's `shell_exec()` so I assume this will need to be written to a file and then executed? Also, excuse my ignorance, but this seems very verbose. Is there nothing built in to windows to accomplish what I need in a more direct manner?

Comment: I've answered the question you asked @Newb4YouBB, I'm not going to answer the question you didn't ask, or adjust this one to cater for a changed question after the fact. Also, if you haven't attempted it, it was hardly fair to accept another answer just six minutes after posting the above comment, (where I couldn't have modified my answer even if I wanted to, or where you could determine which solution was more useful to you for the specific question asked under your provided tags).

Comment: Also, Im fairly certain you can change the accepted answer if another proves to be "more" correct.

Comment: You can @Newb4YouBB, the only issue with being too eager to select one before you've tried them all is that you demotivate the other responders, and potentially prevent additional answers, _(because many members don't like to compete for worthless points)_.